# DAX formula for calculating yesterday's Turnover?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working with POWER BI to develop a commercial dashboard.
The formula I came up with to calculate the previous day's Turnover  is giving me blank results :

```
TRNV_D-1 = CALCULATE(SUM(FACT_SALES[TRNV]) ; PREVIOUSDAY(DIM_TIME[DATE]))
```

there is nothing wrong with the syntax .
PS: DATE is the PK of the dimension TIME .

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the 2nd parameter of CALCULATE with something like this:

FILTER(FACT_SALES , NEXTDAY(DIM_TIME[DATE]) = TODAY())

I reversed the logic because PREVIOUSDAY and NEXTDAY require a column of dates as their parameter.

Maybe it's just me, but I often find DAX totally counterintuitive ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply . I have tried this expression . Still blank .

Comment: Is there a working relationship between FACT_SALES and DIM_TIME ?